# Nested fragments in Android produces IllegalStateException: No activity

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I'm trying to nest fragments in Android SDK 17 but I keep getting an IllegalStateException stating that there is no Activity. I've seen other posts going back to 2011 about this being a bug. I can't believe that four years and many Android versions later this problem still exists. Can someone please show me how I can nest fragments without getting an exception?

Here is the implementations I am using.

```
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentManager;

public class HomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity 
    implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener,
    SinglePaneContainerFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener {

private Fragment containerFragment;
...

containerFragment = new SinglePaneContainerFragment();

getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(
     R.id.content_frame, containerFragment, "single_pain").commit();

FragmentManager childFragmentManager = containerFragment.getChildFragmentManager();

childFragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(
      R.id.fragment_placeholder1, new NestedFragment(), "featured").commit();
```

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: No activity
>               at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1069)
>               at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1064)
>               at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManager.java:1884)
>               at android.app.Fragment.performActivityCreated(Fragment.java:2128)
>               at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:927)
>               at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1082)
>               at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:834)
>               at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1467)
>               at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:452)
>               at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
>               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6837)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199)

Comment: During what part of the life cycle are you calling the replace?

Comment: I'm using a DrawerLayout and this is during the onItemClick() from the Nav list.